# VS Code could not start and showing a black screen

Tags: visual-studio-code

I not sure what have happen to my visual studio code. When I tried to launch it, it cannot start and instead display a black screen. After sometime, an alert message will pop out informing me that the window is not responding. (As shown in the image below)

This is not a GPU issue, as I had tried what some of the posts out there have recommended. I also tried to uninstall and install VS code again but it did not help.

I not sure what I should do next to recover VS code to normal. Not sure is there people that have encountered similar issue as me and have managed to solve the issue. Appreciate if someone can help me. Currently my version of VS code is 1.59.0

[image]

Comment: ... It doesn't seem that there's enough information to diagnose the issue, although questions about programmers' tools are on topic .

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what happen ,but after  I uninstall and reinstall my anaconda , I can resolve the black screen issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the latest version 1.59 ??
URL to Download new:- https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/
You can launch with --disable-extensions from the command line.

Also if you still see the issue with the latest insiders, try launching with --verbose flag, and please attach the log here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks ! The vs-code insider do help me with solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem two days ago so try this solution it worked for me if u have quickheal or any antivirus software

- go to tools tab and search for view quarantine files
- click on view quarantine files
- a window will appear
- if there is any file name or more files select all  and press on add and then press on restore
- then try to open the vs code editor

NICE IF IT WORKS OR ELSE I'LL FIND U AN OTHER WAY